# Shared folder in an Azure VM is not reachable by name on another VM

Tags: network-shares, azure, shared-folders

I have two VMs in Azure, one Windows Server 2019 and one Windows 10.
I am trying to share a folder on the C:\ drive of the Server 2019 VM so that it can be reached from the Windows 10 VM.

I am unable to access the shared folder from the Windows 10 VM when I browse to it by name in the File Explorer, i.e. `\\servername\testFolder\`. It says the folder doesn't exist. I am able to browse to `\\servername\`, but it shows an empty drive.
However, I am able to access the contents using the internal IP address of the Server 2019 VM,  i.e. `\\\10.19.0.4\testFolder\`.

What is happening here, and why is this the case? How can I make it to where I can see my shared folders when I access the server by name, `\\servername\`?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following: go to `control panel`, `user accounts`, `manage credentials`, `windows credentials`, and see if there is an entry for the name of that server. If it exists, delete it, log out and back in, and see if that connects.

Comment: There were no Windows Credential entries at all, so I added one for the server, logged out and logged back in, no change. I then deleted the credential entry I added, logged out and logged back in, still no change. If it helps to know, these two VMs use the exact same username and password